# How should I make a JS variable equal to a MongoDB field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, database

I need to make a JS variable equal to a MongoDB field, and as of now with the code I have, it is working, but not as intended.  It is giving me a whole object, yet I only what the string value in which was assigned to the field. For example, you might have a document that contains the field

```
{name: "dylan"}
```

well I dont want all of that returned, I just want the string dylan. here is the code I have tried.

```
var game = SearchLobby.findOne(
  {profile: Meteor.userId()},
  {game: 1,_id: 0}
);
```

Comment: `findOne` may return `undefined` if there are no matches, so you will need a condition. There is no point to mix white-list and black-list of fields and the `_id` field will always be returned. You will need a conditional expression to get the field value you want if you want to support the `undefined` case.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value is an object, if you add the field you want in a dot notation (**.name**) to your query result, you'll end up with the string value stored in the field.

```
 var game = SearchLobby.findOne(
   {profile: Meteor.userId()},
   {game: 1, _id: 0}
 ).game;
```

Game should return the string value of the name stored inside.

Comment: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'game' of undefined

Comment: can you do SearchLobby.findOne(); ? and paste the results here?

Comment: I am sorry that is db.SearchLobby.findOne(); // assuming you did select database_name_where_collection_exists

Comment: {
 "_id" : "KGpEgZaaCoYCkWz8E",
 "console" : "PS3",
 "players" : "3",
 "mic" : "TRUE",
 "game" : "Fallout 4",
 "profile" : "y2bmypYeo5jC2dg7q"
}

Comment: Great, so in this case, our solution would be 

        var game = db.SearchLobby.findOne(
           {profile: Meteor.userId()},
           {game: 1, _id: 0}
         ).game; //This should return "Fallout 4"

Comment: this isnt working still, apparently "meteor" isnt defined

Comment: Right The other response had it const profile = Meteor.userId(); // I hope this works as I don't know Meteor well

Answer (score 0):

```
const profile = Meteor.userId();
{name: SearchLobby.findOne({profile}, {game: 1,_id: 0}).game}
```

This should do just fine. I don't think that there are any other way how to retrieve game name from document.

Comment: Im not exactly sure how the second line of code is intended to be used, how do I make that equal to the variable? and the name field isnt actually relevant that was just for the example